# How to pass parameters in <a href tag in grails gsp

Tags: grails, gsp

This is the code I am using in the gsp file to fetch the  data to show on the view page:

```
   <datePicker id="startDate" name="startDate" value="${new  
 Date().minus(2).format('yyyy-MM-dd')}"  />
```

the datepicker I am using in the same page.

Now i need to pass the datepicker parameters to this link

```
   <a id="exportIcon" href="${createLink(controller: entityName, action:  
 'mrInventoryExcelExport', params: [StartDate:startDate])}" >
```

the parameter is the `startdate` which i enter manually in the form
Can anyone tell me how can i achieve this.

Comment: I used <g:link> for this and add the function on the onclick event

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a button & submit the form to the given action then either deal with it in the action directly:

gsp:

```
<g:actionSubmit name="exportIcon"       
                action="mrInventoryExcelExport" 
                value="Export"/>
```

controller:

```
def mrInventoryExcelExport() {
    def startDate = params.startDate
    ...
}
```

Or redirect to another action with the startDate:

gsp:

```
<g:actionSubmit name="exportIcon"       
                action="anotherAction" 
                value="Export"/>
```

controller:

```
def anotherAction() {
    redirect( controller: 'entityName', action: 'mrInventoryExcelExport', params:[startDate: params.startDate] )
}
```

Comment: i need the date which is entered on the UI with $('#startDate').val(). It is not working in g:link ...

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use a link rather than posting the form & redirecting?

Comment: yes it is the same reason but i need the parameter value with the redirection

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the mechanics. `GSP` is a server-side technology. Whatever related you have in there, will be processed and converted to HTML, before it is sent to the client/browser.

Now, what you're asking to include/change a parameter in the link, based on the value picked by user; mind you, the link is already created. No chance? Using JavaScript to create that link is your best bet.

**P.S.:** Try to see the page source from the browser, for more insight.